# DIsplay actual error instead of http 500error

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm getting an error on page but I can't figure out what the error is because i'm getting a http 500 page instead of the error. In the very top of the PHP file I wrote:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in the php.ini:

```
display_errors = On
```

I'm using this command to run the web application:

```
php artisan server
```

What am I missing? How could I fix this?

Comment: You can look in `storage/logs` inside of your Laravel project. Most of the time, the 500 error will be written in a file there

Comment: Also, set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your .env file. -- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#debug-mode

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a developer environment and not a production version, you can turn on `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file.

If that doesn't work please try and empty your cache with `php artisan cache:clear` just in case you are caching items. This will clear any cached env variables.

In a development environment this will return the exact error using `Flare\Ignition` that comes bundled with default laravel.

You may also want to install Laravel DebugBar `https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` which is placed at the bottom of the screen for you to see lots of things happening in your app.

Remember NEVER turn on `APP_DEBUG=true` in Production as it will expose all your apps sensitive data.